# Why I get null object reference in android 9 pie

Tags: android, json, android-9.0-pie

I get this error when I testing my app on android 9 pie 28 API version.
It is working in version 8 oreo. It is like didn't get data in JSONobject, what can causing the problem?

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

```
private void downloadJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        DownloadJSON getJSON = new DownloadJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            stocks[i] = obj.getString("sent_date") + "| " + obj.getString("username") + ": " + obj.getString("message");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: debug the value of json and jsonArray in `loadIntoListView`

Comment: post your logs here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the server you are trying to access is not secure i.e it is using HTTP (not HTTPS).

Android P uses HTTPS by default. What this means is that if you are using unencrypted HTTP requests in your app, the app will work fine in all versions of Android except Android P.

To avoid this security, try below changes in your app code.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and in res/xml add file named : `network_security_config.xml`

in `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        //  Add host of your download URL in below line. 
        //   ie. if url is  "https://www.google.com/search?source=...."
        //   then just add "www.google.com"
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.google.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was facing past one week. I thought may be there is some problem with my code. But I don't know google had added this security in android 9+ devices.